# Linux shell: LOOP for create file in each folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, for-loop

experts

I want to create file in each folder . Here is my command

```
for i in `ls`;do cd $i;touch test.txt;done

-bash: cd: 10/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 2/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 3/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 4/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 5/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 6/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 7/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 8/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: 9/: No such file or directory
```

It only generate `test.txt` in folder `1/`, the rest folder are blank. I think the reason is my command lack of `{ }` to clarify the scale of LOOP for .

could you please help me update my command?

Comment: sorry , I should use `( )` instead of `{ }` to achieve it .

Comment: it should be like `for i in */;do (cd $i;`ls`;cd -);done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for dir in */; do
   touch "$dir/test.txt"
done
```

1. There's no need to `cd` into a directory to create a file there.
2. Don't parse the output of `ls`.  The output of `ls` is only for looking at. Parsing it will break if your files or directories have names containing literal newlines or spaces.
3. The pattern `*/` will match any directory in the current directory.
4. Quote your variable expansions. Your code would break if `IFS` is set to a digit.

If you *really* need to do a `cd` into the directory, do it in a subshell. The changed working directory only affects the subshell and there is no need to `cd` back.

```
for dir in */; do
   ( cd "$dir" && touch test.txt )
done
```

Comment: yes, it is truly right. my original purpose is update the command like ` for i in */;do (cd $i;ls;cd -);done`, but your command is more efficency.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that you have the following 10 folders in your current working directory:

```
tree .
.
├── 1
├── 10
├── 2
├── 3
├── 4
├── 5
├── 6
├── 7
├── 8
└── 9
```

you can run the following command, to create your files:

```
for d in `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do touch "$d"/test.txt; done
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
tree .
.
├── 1
│   └── test.txt
├── 10
│   └── test.txt
├── 2
│   └── test.txt
├── 3
│   └── test.txt
├── 4
│   └── test.txt
├── 5
│   └── test.txt
├── 6
│   └── test.txt
├── 7
│   └── test.txt
├── 8
│   └── test.txt
└── 9
    └── test.txt

10 directories, 10 files
```

**Explanations:**

`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d` will get all the folders that are exactly 1 level under your current working folder if you omit `-mindepth 1` then you will have a file created in your current working directory since `.` will be selected, if you omit `-maxdepth 1` then file will be created recursively at any depth level, also `-type d` will allow to filter only on directories.

You can then use a loop to create the files or even `xargs` command would be enough

Comment: thanks, you inspired me , that I should type `for i in `ls`;do touch $i/test.txt;done` . but your method is more accurate to make sure right result.

Answer (score 1):

You `cd` into a directory, but you don't `cd`back out. Assuming that the first directory in the list is `1`, your script first changes into `1`, and next tries to change into `1/10`, which does not exist.

You could do a `cd -` after touching the file.

Even better, you avoid the `cd` altogether and do a `touch $i/test.txt` instead.

Of course, the script as written is not very robust: It breaks, if the current directory contains plain files, and it breaks if it contains entries which have spaces in their names - but this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your command a bit,

```
for i in `ls -1`;do touch "$i"/test.txt;done
```